# Django: CSRF verification failed

Tags: django

I am trying to submit a non-ssl wrapped page to an ssl wrapped page, but I get this error.

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Reason given for failure:
    Referer checking failed - http://<domain>/ does not match https://<domain>/.
```

That is, I am trying to submit a username/password page to the login method.

How can I do this without getting this error?

Thanks
ERic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider it to be safe, here's how to [specifically exempt a normal view from CSRF checking](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#exceptions).

**However**, I'm assuming you're talking about the `contrib.auth` views, then you may have to write your own custom version and apply the `@csrf_exempt` decorator instead of the one that enforces it (ie, copy, paste, change decorator on the method - it's not as painful as it sounds).

Absolutely worst-case, sledgehammer-to-crack-nut solution: [force-disable CSRF altogether](http://johnmc.co/llum/disable-csrf-protection-for-django-1-2/), for all views, even `django.contrib.*` ones that try to enforce CSRF. Upside is you don't have to hack/fork contrib modules; downside is - well - no CSRF...

Comment: Thanks! I am not too worried about CSRF because this is an intranet site that doesn't allow access to it from the internet. :)

Comment: I went with the 2nd option you have there and it works nicely! :)  Thanks. :)